# JPA Multiple Foreign Key

Tags: jpa, ejb

I am working on a EJB/JPA project.

I have two tables: 
`BusinessOwner` and `Clients`.

Each of these tables has a super class, `Person`.

I have a table that keeps all their transactions, both `BusinessOwner` and `Clients`.
In the Transaction table, I have a field `UserID`, that points to the `primary key` of both `BusinessOwners` and `Clients`, as a `foreign key`.

How do i map these as in my entity class.

Comment: Are you using the same `UserID` to map two different tables?

Comment: Same question as @rbedger, do you have a `BusinessOwner` and a `Client` for each row of `Transaction` or do you have one reference to a `Person` that can be either a `BusinessOwner` or a `Client`?

Comment: I have a UserID field in the Transaction Table that can either be a BusinessOwner's primary key or a Client's primary key. How do u think i can map it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have a OneToMany from Person to Transaction and a ManyToOne from Transaction to Person, but this depends on how you have mapped inheritance?